# Finding last row in column when adjacent column has data past original column end point

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that has two columns G and H. Column G has 25 rows that are not empty and column H has 15 columns. I have written some vba code to find the last row in column H but it selects all the way down to column G's end not stopping at column H's end. Is there a way to write the code to not look at whats in column G? I have added the code I have below.

Thanks!

```
ws.Range("H2:H" & Range("H" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Select
```

Comment: My guess is that there are formulas in column H that return `""`.  BTW, the line should be `ws.Range("H2", ws.Range("H" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp)).Select`

Comment: So is there a way to have an if formula put a nothing so I can find the last row?

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to avoid any *NULL* cells at the bottom column column **H**:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim nr As Long

    nr = [MAX((H:H<>"")*(ROW(H:H)))]
    Range("H" & nr).Select
End Sub
```

This is quite slow so consider replacing `H:H` with something like `H1:H9999`

Answer (score 0):

Try this line instead of the one you have:

```
ws.Range("H2", ws.Range("H:H").Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious)).Select
```

It will find the last cell with a value that is not `""`.

The photo shows that there is a formula in H11:

[image]

But the following code:

```
Sub finnnn()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet13")

Debug.Print ws.Range("H1", ws.Range("H:H").Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious)).Address

End Sub
```

When run lists `$H$1:$H$5` in the immediate window:

[image]